# vb.net problems with invoke

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, winforms, invoke

I have a thread that runs background jobs and is required to update the GUI once in a while. My program has been designed so that when the user clicks off of a form, the thread and background operations still run, yet the controls have been disposed (for memory management purposes).

I have been using Invoke() and "If Control.Created = True" to make sure that the thread can successfully update the controls without running into any exceptions. However, when the form is recreated, all "Control.Created" values are false and Invoke() fails with "{"Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window handle has been created."}"

My guess is that this has something to do with the fact that when the form is recreated it is assigned different handles and that the "Invoke()" is looking at the old handle. SO my question is, how do I fix this?

EDIT: As per requested, the code for opening the form and where the bg thread works from

Opening the DropLogMDIalt form is simply

```
    FormCTRL.Show()
```

The Background Thread runs when the control is modified so that the NumericUpDown is more than 0 (so that there is something to countdown from)

```
    Private Sub NLauncherTerminateInput_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles DLScanInterval.ValueChanged
    If DLScanInterval.Created = True Then
        DLTimerControlValue = DLScanInterval.Value
        If DLTimerControlValue = 0 Then
            CancelDropLogTimer()
        Else
            If DLScanIntervalControl.Active = False Then
                BeginDropLogTimer()
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub


Public Sub BeginDropLogTimer()
    Dim N As New Threading.Thread(AddressOf DropLogTimerIntervalThreadWorker)
    N.Start()
    DLScanIntervalControl.ThreadID = N.ManagedThreadId
    DLScanIntervalControl.Active = True
End Sub

Public Sub CancelDropLogTimer()
    DLScanIntervalControl.Active = False
End Sub

    Public Sub DropLogTimerIntervalThreadWorker()
    DLScanTimerSecondsLeft = DLTimerControlValue * 60
    Dim s As Integer = DLTimerControlValue
    Do Until 1 = 2
        DLScanTimerSecondsLeft = DLTimerControlValue * 60
        Do Until DLScanTimerSecondsLeft <= 0
            If Not (DLTimerControlValue = 0 Or DLScanIntervalControl.CancelPending = True) Then
            Else
                Exit Sub
            End If

            If Not DLTimerControlValue = s Then
                DLScanTimerSecondsLeft = DLTimerControlValue * 60
                s = DLTimerControlValue
            End If

            Dim ToInvoke As New MethodInvoker(Sub()
                                                  Timer(DLScanTimerSecondsLeft, ":", DLScanIntervalTB)
                                              End Sub)
            If (Me.IsHandleCreated) Then
                If (InvokeRequired) Then
                    Invoke(ToInvoke)
                Else
                    ToInvoke()
                End If
            End If


            Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
            DLScanTimerSecondsLeft -= 1
        Loop

        CompareScan = True
        PerformScan()
    Loop
End Sub
```

The thread is simply called by declaring a new thread.thread, however, I have created a class and a variable that the thread uses to check if it should still be running or not (similarly to how a backgroundworker would) this is illustrated by the "DLScanIntervalControl.CancelPending"

The form is then closed later by

```
Form.Close()
```

It can be reopened if the user clicks on a label that then uses the same method as shown above (FormCTRL.Show())

Comment: I have a suspicion that if you create the controls again (including the form) then they are not the same controls as the previous ones (i.e. they have different handles). Can you just `.Hide` the appropriate form(s) instead? ... Ah, yes, from the documentation for [Form.Close()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.close%28v=vs.110%29.aspx): "When a form is closed, all resources created within the object are closed and the form is disposed."

Comment: I had a similar error when trying to use delegates and I found that the handle is only created when it's "needed".  I'm not sure what constitutes "needed", but you can force it to create the handle by accessing the Handle property of the object.
What I had to do in my application is loop through all controls on the form and check the IsHandleCreated property.  If it was false, then I just called "Dim tmp = ctrl.Handle" and went on my merry way.
It's rather ghetto, but it may help you here (If you still need the help)

Comment: This is a typical example of why the UI is supposed to be off-limits to other threads. Instead of adding overhead to a background thread to update a potentially existing UI.. Have the form itself handle the updating appropriately and in a controlled manner.

Answer (score 1):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invokerequired(v=vs.110).aspx):

> *"If the control's handle does not yet exist, InvokeRequired searches up the control's parent chain until it finds a control or form that does have a window handle. If no appropriate handle can be found, the InvokeRequired method returns false."*

In other words, you need to verify that the handle is created and then check if invoke is required.

```
If(Me.IsHandleCreated) Then
    If(Me.InvokeRequired) Then
        '...
    Else
        '...
    End If
End If
```

Comment: Me.IsHandleCreated just returns "False". Me referring to DropLogMDI is the form I am observing at this breakpoint

Comment: `just returns "False"` Could you elaborate? I'm not sure I'm following you.

Comment: The code that updates the GUI was moved inside the "If (Me.IsHandleCreated) statement but it never runs since IsHandleCreated returns as false. Could my problem have something to do with the fact that the Background Thread's code is run inside the DropLogMDI class (the form that gets recreated)?

Comment: @user3494322 you should provide some code in your question

Comment: It might. Can you update your question to include where and how you create the bg thread and how you reference/invoke the form?

Comment: Thanks, I have included the code now. Hopefully this covers everything you requested.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar error when trying to use delegates to update controls on a form in another thread. I found that the handle is only created when it's "needed". I'm not sure what constitutes "needed", but you can force it to create the handle by accessing the Handle property of the object. 
What I had done in my application is this:

```
  ' Iterate through each control on the form, and if the handle isn't created yet, call the
  ' Handle property to force it to be created
  For Each ctrl As Control In Me.Controls
     While Not ctrl.IsHandleCreated
        Dim tmp = ctrl.Handle
        tmp = Nothing
     End While ' Not ctrl.IsHandleCreated
  Next ' ctrl As Control In Me.Controls
```

It's rather ghetto, but it may help you here (If you still need the help)

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue here has nothing to do with invoking, but references. Following this pseudocode...

```
Dim A As New Form1
A.Show()

''Spawn background thread with a reference to A

A.Dispose()

Dim B As New Form1
B.Show()
```

The thread is attempting to refer to the first instance of `Form1` above which is disposed and will always stay that way.

If you want the thread to be able to update *any* form then you need to give the thread a (synchronised) way to refer to the form...

```
Public Class Worker

    Private Target As Form1
    Private TargetLock As New Object

    Public Sub SetTargetForm(Frm as Form1)
        SyncLock TargetLock
            Target = Frm
        End SyncLock
    End Sub

    Public Sub DoWork() ''The worker thread method
        ''Do work as usual then...
        SyncLock TargetLock
            If Target IsNot Nothing AndAlso Target.IsHandleCreated Then
                If Target.InvokeRequired
                    Target.Invoke(...)
                Else
                    ...
                End If
            End If
        End SyncLock
    End Sub
End Class
```

This way, when a new form is available, you can inform the worker thread using `SetTargetForm()` and it will update the appropriate one.

Of course, you'd be better off refactoring the "Update UI" checks and invoke calls into a different method for simplicity/maintainability but you get the point.

Note that I haven't got an IDE to hand so there may be typos.

One final point... I'd question the value of disposing a form for memory management purposes. Controls are fairly lightweight in terms of memory and it's far more common for an object used by the form to be a memory hog than the form itself. Are you sure you're getting a real benefit for this added complexity?

Comment: Thanks! I will take a proper look at this in the morning. Concerning USER/GDI objects, the benefits from this warrant the extra challenge in what I am trying to do as this was a problem in the previous version of my program where nothing was disposed (the program is run in environments where they aren't many free objects available)

Comment: Ah, Ok... Limited User/GDI handles is a different matter entirely. I've hit that limit myself on some (very) complex forms generated from data. Let me know if this helps at all